# Android App POST-ing to PHP Laravel Server

Tags: php, android, laravel, postman

I have an android app that I've set to POST some data to my PHP Laravel server, however I get a 405 error and I don't know why( trying to POST via Postman works just fine)

This is my android code:

```
 String URL_POST = "http://192.168.2.102/device/id";
 btnGoi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            InsertSV();
        }

    });


private void InsertSV() {

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_POST, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(IdDeviceActivity.this, error + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String Id = edtId.getText().toString();
            params.put("ID", Id);

            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

And this is my PHP Laravel one(I am using xampp to start it):

```
public function checkDeviceId(Request $request){

    $id = $request->input('ID');
    $code=LicenceCodes::where('device_id',$id)->first();
    if($code==null){
        return response('Wrong device id.'.$id, 405)
            ->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    }
    else
    {
        return response('Device added'.$id, 200)
            ->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    }
```

And my routing:

```
Route::post('/device/id', 'DeviceController@checkDeviceId');
```

Knowing that it's working just fine with Postman, I think there might be an android problem? Or I'm not passing the parameter properly, I'm really not sure....

EDIT: However, I've tried to POST to a simple php file in my xampp folder and for that it works fine

LATER LATER EDIT: I see that I get 405 Method Not allowed on Postman aswell, however I still get the good response in body and that's why I was fooled. How should I fix the 405 error ?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Had to switch some status error codes and it works fine now.

Comment: You can certainly be a bit more explicit with your answer. It might help someone else too.

Comment: I guess i am having same problem. Can you explain how you solved it ??